# Timer object in a class library?

Tags: c#, timer, class-library

I tried following code to run timer in class library but timer_Elapsed wasn't fired. I also tried using timer from System.Windows.Forms but it didn't worked.

```
private static void SetTimer(DateTime dateTime)
{
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    TimeSpan timeSpan = dateTime - DateTime.Now;
    timer.Interval = timeSpan.Milliseconds;
    timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Start();
}

private static void timer_Elapsed(object myobject, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    timer.Enabled = false; 
    timer.Stop(); 
    Start(_appCastURL, _remindLaterAt, _remindLaterFormat); 
}
```

Comment: have you called `timer.Start()` somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed Static from the timer declaration and remove static from event and SetTimer method, put it in the class extending Form in the class library and it worked.

```
private void SetTimer(DateTime remindLater)
{
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    TimeSpan timeSpan = remindLater - DateTime.Now;
    timer.Interval = (int) timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds;
    timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
    timer.Start();
}

private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    AutoUpdater.Start(appCast, remindLaterAt, remindLaterFormat);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to `.Start()` it :)

Answer (score 2):

A forms based timer won't work, it requires an active message pump to run in order to process the tick events.

The [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) will work as intended, but only if you [`Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.start.aspx) it or enable it (via `Enabled = true`). Note that the `Elapsed` event will fire on an arbitrary `ThreadPool` thread by default. You can use the [`SynchronizingObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject.aspx) property in order to control the thread the event runs on.

Comment: as you can see my SetTimer method is Static so althogh i implement ISynchronizeInvoke interface i can't assign my current class to SynchronizingObject. Without using SynchronizingObject it didn't work. Can i use System.Threading.Timer instead of this timer?

Comment: @RaviPatel The lack of the SynchonizingObject wouldn't stop it from working, I'm guessing your problem is elsewhere - your code doesn't even show you starting the timer, just setting it up ready to start. Call `.Start()` or `.Enabled = true` in order to actually run the timer.

Comment: @RaviPatel You need to describe how "it didn't work" as there is nothing wrong with the code (assuming of course your Interval is a sensible value). Are you saying the event isn't called?

Comment: yes i tried setting the break point but it didn't called. Here is my event 'private static void timer_Elapsed(object myobject, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Enabled = false;
            timer.Stop();
            Start(_appCastURL, _remindLaterAt, _remindLaterFormat);
        }'

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the System.Threading.Timer